# Temporal GRASS GIS framework

Tags: grass-gis, time

I am trying to follow the tutorial posted [here](http://geostat-course.org/Topic_Gebbert).  When I get to this part "Extraction of seasonal mean temperature" and run this code:

```
t.rast.extract \
  input=temperature_mean_1950_2011_seasonal \
  output=temperature_mean_1950_2011_spring \
  where="start_time = date_trunc('year', start_time \
         + interval '2 months')" \
expression="temperature_mean_1950_2011_seasonal/100.0" \
  base=temp_mean_spring
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Unable to get map ids from register table
   <temperature_mean_1950_2011_seasonal_PERMANENT_raster_register>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/grass-7.0.svn/scripts/t.rast.extract", line 91, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/local/grass-7.0.svn/scripts/t.rast.extract", line 85, in main
base, nprocs, register_null)
File "/usr/local/grass-7.0.svn/etc/python/grass/temporal/extract.py", line 95, in extract_dataset
rows = sp.get_registered_maps("id", where, "start_time", dbif)
File "/usr/local/grass-7.0.svn/etc/python/grass/temporal/abstract_space_time_dataset.py", line 905, in get_registered_maps
dbif.cursor.execute(sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "'2 months'": syntax error
```

I am using the data specified in the presentation (mean temperatures dataset downloaded from http://eca.knmi.nl/download/ensembles/data/Grid_0.25deg_reg/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [date_trunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) works in PostgreSQL:

```
# SELECT date_trunc('year', timestamp '2001-11-16 20:38:40' + interval '2 months');
     date_trunc      
---------------------
 2002-01-01 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

While in SQLite it gives the error you get:

```
> SELECT date_trunc('year', timestamp '2001-11-16 20:38:40' + interval '2 months');
Error: near "'2001-11-16 20:38:40'": syntax error
```

However, in SQLite there is a function [datetime](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function which does the job:

```
> SELECT datetime('2001-11-16 20:38:40', '2 months', 'start of year');
2002-01-01 00:00:00
```

The current version of [presentation](http://geostat-course.org/system/files/Presentation_0.pdf) from [geostat-course](http://geostat-course.org/Topic_Gebbert) provides a different command:

```
t.rast.extract \
    input=temperature_mean_1950_2011_seasonal \
    output=temperature_mean_1950_2011_spring \
    where="start_time = datetime(start_time, \
    ’start of year’, ’2 month’)" \
    expression="temperature_mean_1950_2011_seasonal/100.0"
    base=temp_mean_spring
```

This command relies on SQLite backend, not PostgreSQL. And the function call in temporal SQL `where` is actually different from the examples above (and possibly from the previous version) and returns March:

```
> SELECT datetime('2001-11-16 20:38:40', 'start of year', '2 month');
2001-03-01 00:00:00
```

The `datetime` parameters are evaluated after each other, so `'start of year'` rounds to nearest smaller year (similarly to `data_trunc('year', ...`) and nect parameter `'2 month'` (or `'+2 months'`) adds two month resulting in March of year given in first parameter.

Note that the default backend of GRASS GIS temporal framework is SQLite (SQLite3), the PostgreSQL backend is an alternative. The connection to backend is handled by [t.connect](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/t.connect.html) module.